# import JSON file to MS SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, json

I make an API call to a URL using C# and it returns JSon response and i download the json file.

i would like to write the json data to database for use by a web application.
how can i import the json file into sql or write it direct from my c# program to db . am using sql 2016

My JSon file looks as follows :

```
{

    "Items": [
    {
        "LocalTimestamp": "2017-07-05T18:59:29+02:00",
        "Id": 653914348,
        "Description": "Trip Shutdown",
        "Processed": false,
        "Position": [
            27.90225,
            -26.07706
        ]
    },
    {
        "LocalTimestamp": "2017-07-05T08:41:08+02:00",
        "Id": 653709051,
        "Description": "Trip Startup",
        "Processed": false,
        "Position": [
            27.90229,
            -26.07753
        ]
    },
    {
        "LocalTimestamp": "2017-07-05T07:42:19+02:00",
        "Id": 653692142,
        "Description": "Trip Shutdown",
        "Processed": false,
        "Position": [
            27.90228,
            -26.07708
        ]
    },
    {
        "LocalTimestamp": "2017-07-05T07:21:47+02:00",
        "Id": 653683088,
        "Description": "Trip Startup",
        "Processed": false,
        "Position": [
            27.9222,
            -26.04318
        ]
    },
    {
        "LocalTimestamp": "2017-07-05T07:21:00+02:00",
        "Id": 653682830,
        "Description": "Trip Shutdown",
        "Processed": false,
        "Position": [
            27.92348,
            -26.04612
        ]
    },
    {
        "LocalTimestamp": "2017-07-04T10:15:35+02:00",
        "Id": 653330923,
        "Description": "Trip Shutdown",
        "Processed": false,
        "Position": [
            27.997,
            -26.05747
        ]
    },
    {
        "LocalTimestamp": "2017-07-04T09:41:19+02:00",
        "Id": 653320268,
        "Description": "Trip Startup",
        "Processed": false,
        "Position": [
            28.02899,
            -26.20546
        ]
    },
    {
        "LocalTimestamp": "2017-07-04T09:32:54+02:00",
        "Id": 653317769,
        "Description": "Trip Shutdown",
        "Processed": false,
        "Position": [
            28.0293,
            -26.20549
        ]
    },
    {
        "LocalTimestamp": "2017-07-03T18:40:43+02:00",
        "Id": 653089737,
        "Description": "Trip Shutdown",
        "Processed": false,
        "Position": [
            27.90228,
            -26.07707
        ]
    },
    {
        "LocalTimestamp": "2017-07-03T18:29:01+02:00",
        "Id": 653086470,
        "Description": "Trip Startup",
        "Processed": false,
        "Position": [
            27.94599,
            -26.07828
        ]
    },
    {
        "LocalTimestamp": "2017-07-03T18:26:30+02:00",
        "Id": 653085810,
        "Description": "Trip Shutdown",
        "Processed": false,
        "Position": [
            27.94662,
            -26.07807
        ]
    },
    {
        "LocalTimestamp": "2017-07-03T18:15:50+02:00",
        "Id": 653082613,
        "Description": "Trip Startup",
        "Processed": false,
        "Position": [
            27.98847,
            -26.05269
        ]
    },
    {
        "LocalTimestamp": "2017-07-03T18:13:15+02:00",
        "Id": 653082018,
        "Description": "Trip Shutdown",
        "Processed": false,
        "Position": [
            27.99036,
            -26.05341
        ]
    }
 ],
 "HasMoreResults": false
}
```

Comment: you can deserialize the json string which you received and save that to database using c#. In database, you need to create tables based on your json string structure.

Comment: A typical approach would be deconstructing the JSON file into an object representation of the JSON message using JSON.NET and sending the output to your database where a table using the same format was added.

Comment: [Saving JSON objects to SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35649357/saving-json-objects-to-sql-server-database)

Comment: See my answer. I have updated and it is giving output, what you expect

Comment: @Carlos.net - Glad to hear it worked for you. Accept as answer by ticking it. Such that if others are facing same type of issue it will be helpful for them :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. As i have mentioned in my comment, you have to de-serialize the json string which you received to object/class and save that class/object properties to database using c#.

In database, you need to create tables based on your "json string structure" or "class/object".

According to your json string the class should be like below

```
public class Item
{
    public string LocalTimestamp { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Processed { get; set; }
    public List<double> Position { get; set; }
}

public class AllItems
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public bool HasMoreResults { get; set; }
}
```

To de-serialize the json string, below is the code and for that, you need the namespace "`System.Web.Script.Serialization`".

```
string jsonstring = @"define your json string here";
//Deserialize the json string to the object/class format
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
AllItems allItemsObj = serializer.Deserialize<AllItems>(jsonstring);
```

Create your database table as per the json string structure

```
CREATE TABLE AllItemsTable (
    ItemIdPrimary int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    LocalTimestamp nvarchar(255),
    Id int,
    Description nvarchar(255),
    Processed nvarchar(255),
    Position1 nvarchar(50),
    Position2 nvarchar(50)

    PRIMARY KEY (ItemIdPrimary)
);
```

> Here the complete code to de-serialize the json string and save data
>   to database.
>
> For jsonstring, i have added a json file named as "test1.json" inside
>   the application and copied your json string to the json file.Late i am
>   consuming the json from that file("test1.json")

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace DeserializeJson2ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Get the Json string
            string jsonstring = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\My Apps\Console Applications\DeserializeJson2ConsoleApp\DeserializeJson2ConsoleApp\test1.json");
            //Deserialize the json string to the object/class format
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            AllItems allItemsObj = serializer.Deserialize<AllItems>(jsonstring);
            //Save the deserilized object/class to database
            //Get your connection string defined inside the Web.config(for web application) / App.config(for console/windows/wpf/classlibrary application) file
            string myConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            //Create your Sql Connection here
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
            {
                //Open the sql connection
                con.Open();
                //Loop each items and save to database
                foreach (var item in allItemsObj.Items)
                {
                    //Save/Insert to database
                    if(SaveToDatabase(con, item))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Success : " + item.Description + " Saved into database");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error : " + item.Description + " unable to Saved into database");
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.Read();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Insert to database
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="con"></param>
        /// <param name="aItemObj"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        static bool SaveToDatabase(SqlConnection con,Item aItemObj)
        {
            try
            {
                string insertQuery = @"Insert into AllItemsTable(LocalTimestamp,Id,Description,Processed,Position1,Position2) Values(@LocalTimestamp,@Id,@Description,@Processed,@Position1,@Position2)";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LocalTimestamp",aItemObj.LocalTimestamp));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", aItemObj.Id));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Description", aItemObj.Description));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Processed", aItemObj.Processed));
                    for(int index=0;index<aItemObj.Position.Count;index++)
                    {
                        if(index==0)
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Position1", aItemObj.Position[index].ToString()));
                        else
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Position2", aItemObj.Position[index].ToString()));
                    }
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception objEx)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string LocalTimestamp { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool Processed { get; set; }
        public List<double> Position { get; set; }
    }

    public class AllItems
    {
        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
        public bool HasMoreResults { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is the message in console after data saved to the database.

[image]

And here is the data which has been saved to the database.

[image]

Hope, it solves your problem. Revert me back if you have any issues.